# Accessing BitmapData erratically shows "cannot access protected memory"

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, garbage-collection, bitmapdata

I'm working with bitmaps in C#, and using the unsafe BitmapData class to access the pixel data directly.

Erratically and for no apparent reason I get this error (rarely, probably every hour or so)

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

This occurs when I try to get/set a pixel, using unsafe code. Is there a way to solve this? I'm keeping object refs to both the Bitmap and the BitmapData in Lists so I don't think it has been destroyed by the GC, however the GC might have moved it around. Is this possible?

Note that this doesn't happen at any predictable time (like at startup, or init, or when the image code is run). What could be hapenning? I thought a locked bitmap was locked, and the memory wouldn't just get inaccessible suddenly but this is not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you pinning your pointer? EDIT: Actually, you shouldn't have to. Nevermind!

Comment: I don't know what pinning is, but I have stored (cached) the `int Stride` and the `IntPtr Scan0` in a wrapper class "LockedBitmap". Does .NET move the bitmap and update these pointers? If so I may be using an older (and therefore incorrect) version of the pointers.

Comment: Once you call `UnlockBits`, the GC can take over. Are you calling `UnlockBits` at any point?

Comment: This is the way unsafe code fails.  The garbage collector is not involved, pixel data for a bitmap is stored in unmanaged memory.  You have a bug in your code, you'll need to fix it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - No I'm not calling unlock bits at all.